# Need the greatest value in new column

Tags: sql, max, calculated-columns

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID     amt_1     amt_2     amt_3     amt_4
001    100.00    300.00     50.00    200.00
002    200.00    400.00    100.00    200.00 
003    700.00     50.0     200.00    700.00
```

And I want to make a new column that carries only the greatest value per ID ie:

```
ID     amt_1     amt_2     amt_3     amt_4     NEW_COL
001    100.00    300.00     50.00    200.00    300.00
002    200.00    400.00    100.00    200.00    400.00
003    700.00     50.0     200.00    700.00    700.00
```

Not that I think a CTE would help me, but let me say I cannot use them because this is being imported to Tableau which does not recognize CTE's.

Comment: What DBMS are you selecting this from?

Comment: @paqogomez I'm assuming SQL Server since he mentions CTE's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CASE Statement` you can find the largest value among the columns.

```
SELECT ID,
       amt_1,
       amt_2,
       amt_3,
       amt_4,
       CASE
         WHEN amt_1 >= amt_2 AND amt_1 >= amt_3 AND amt_1 >= amt_4 THEN amt_1
         WHEN amt_2 >= amt_1 AND amt_2 >= amt_3 AND amt_2 >= amt_4 THEN amt_2
         WHEN amt_3 >= amt_1 AND amt_3 >= amt_2 AND amt_3 >= amt_4 THEN amt_3
         WHEN amt_4 >= amt_1 AND amt_4 >= amt_2 AND amt_4 >= amt_3 THEN amt_4
       END NEW_COL
FROM   Tablename
```

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2008 or later versions` then try this

```
SELECT ID,amt_1,amt_2,amt_3,amt_4,
  (SELECT Max(amt) FROM (VALUES (amt_1), (amt_2), (amt_3),(amt_4)) AS value(amt))  NEW_COL
FROM tablename
```

Comment: I think this is what I will have to do. I was just hoping there would be a way to do it with less text.  Anywho - I'll plug this in and report back

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL, you can use subselect to do something like this :

```
SELECT MAX(SELECT amt_1 FROM table_name
UNION
SELECT amt_2 FROM table_name
UNION
SELECT amt_3 FROM table_name
// ...) as maxValue, id FROM table_name
```

I'm just thinking loudly, try to see if this pseudo code works, note that you can create a view or a temporary table to store the table returned from the Union of the 4 selects.

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

If you use a set of unions in a subquery to select each `amt_#` value, and then select the max of each id from that (grouping by `ID`) it should get you what you need:

```
select
    mt.ID,
    mt.amt_1,
    mt.amt_2,
    mt.amt_3,
    mt.amt_4,
    max(amt)
from (
    select
        ID,
        amt_1 as amt
    from MyTable
    Union
    select
        ID,
        amt_2
    from MyTable
    Union
    select
        ID,
        amt_3
    from MyTable
    Union
    select
        ID,
        amt_4
    from MyTable
) t1
    inner join MyTable mt on t1.id = mt.ID
group by mt.ID, amt_1, amt_2, amt_3, amt_4
```